# Does "resist all" from different sources stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, fighter, damage-resistance

So I've looked in PHB1 and 2, as well as all over the internets, and I can't find a clear answer.

I play a level 12 Dreadnought Fighter, wearing Rimefire Plate armor.  The armor gives a static "Resist 1 All," and my Dreadnought Path feature "Dreadnought Action" grants me "Resist 10 All" when I use an action point to attack.  After spending an action point, would I have Resist 11 All or Resist 10 All?

I also have items and a power that can grant me resist all.  Do any of these stack?  I've been playing it as they don't, but I'd love if they did.

Comment: While I can't help you since I don't know D&D 4e all that well I did add the 4e tag so hopefully the folks who do know will respond a little quicker!

Answer (score 11):

**Nope**

Unless it specifically says otherwise they do not stack. It's item 28 on the [PHB FAQ](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1396/~/faq-for-the-player%27s-handbook!) over at Wizards.com.

Note that this applies to all resistances, so you'd only get the Resist 10 All.

Edit:

Here's a snippet from the Compendium entry that is linked in the FAQ.

> **Not Cumulative**: Resistances against the same damage type are not
>   cumulative. Only the highest
>   resistance applies. For example, if
>   you have resist 5 cold and then gain
>   resist 10 cold, you have resist 10
>   cold, not resist 15 cold. Similarly,
>   if you have resist 5 cold and then
>   gain resist 2 to all damage, you still
>   have resist 5 cold, not resist 7 cold.

Comment: Thanks Cthos. This isn't the answer I was hoping for, but it is what I expected. Thanks for quoting your source too.